# Unable to access rails application with Nginx + Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, unicorn

Yesterday I was able to see default page like you see [here](http://nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/index_page2.png).

But today I modified config for nginx to access my rails application which is running on unicorn and started getting 404.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
  # multi_accept on;
}

http {
  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  ##
  # Virtual Host Configs
  ##

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.integrity_matters.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /home/ubuntu/integrity_matters/current/public;

  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

**MY_APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb**

```
root = "/home/imdeploy/integrity_matters/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.integrity_matters.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30

# Force the bundler gemfile environment variable to
# reference the capistrano "current" symlink
before_exec do |_|
  ENV\["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"\] = File.join(root, 'Gemfile')
end][2]
```

I also verified that the security groups attached to EC2 allows 22, 80 and 443 ports. Please find [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Keet.png) security rules for EC2.

I restarted nginx and unicorn many times and verified that nginx and unicorn are running properly.

I also verified nginx access and error logs but could not see any activity there.

Please help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to fix it. The issue was AWS was expecting to make nginx SSL aware.

So to make it work I created self signed certificate and modify nginx configuration. Below is the final configuration.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
upstream integrity_matters_server {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.integrity_matters.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen   80;
  server_name ec2-52-10-245-227.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://ec2-52-10-245-227.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com permanent;
}

server {
  listen   443;
  server_name ec2-52-10-245-227.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
  root /home/ubuntu/integrity_matters/current/public;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx_im.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx_im.key;
  ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri @integrity_matters;
  location @integrity_matters {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://integrity_matters_server;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616521/nginx-configuration-leads-to-endless-redirect-loop) also useful while we were making SSL configuration.

Answer (score 0):

nginx.conf included config file path is `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` but your default config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

Change `sites-enabled` to `sites-available`, and try again.