# Rails app migrating to AWS Elastic Beanstalk :: Bad Gateway (502)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

So I'm migrating from Heroku to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and testing out the waters.  I'm following this documentation:

[AWS Docs :: Deploy Rails app to AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html)

However after following the documentation I keep receiving a Bad Gateway 502 (error).

Here's the specs of my app:

- Rails 4.1.8
- Ruby 2.1.7
- Server Puma

So I checked my `/log/nginx/error.log` and here is what I see:

> 2015/11/24 06:44:12 [crit] 2689#0: *4719 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No     such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.13.129, server: _, request: "G    ET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "my-app-env-mympay5afd.elasticbeanstalk.com"

From this [AWS Forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=579590) it appears as though Puma is not starting correctly.

So the three log files that I have taken a look at are:

- /var/log/eb-activity.log
- /var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
- /var/log/eb-version-deployment.log

and none of them seem to indicate any errors except for the "secret_key_base" error which I fixed (I used the `eb setenv SECRET_KEY_BASE=[some_special_key]` command).

One thing that could hint at the source of the issue is `/var/log/nginx/rotated/error.log1448330461.gz` has the following content

> 2015/11/24 01:06:55 [warn] 2680#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:39
>     2015/11/24 01:06:55 [warn] 2680#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

But they seem to be warnings rather than severe show stoppers.

Are there any other files that I should be taking a look at?

As another point of reference, I've looked at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071627/502-bad-gateway-nginx-puma-rails-3-2-on-elastic-beanstalk) which would seem to imply that I need to enable SSL in order for all of this to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.

In my 'production.rb' I had a force_ssl setting and I didn't set up SSL yet since I was just starting out.